# Android Compose horizontal alignment problem

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-layout

I have a Android Compose layout issue. This example is simplified. So please don't worry about the hierarchy.

A card should contain two main content areas. One should take all available space starting from the left side. The other one is located at the right side and has a fixed width.
I use a Spacer to keep it at the right side of the card.

It works fine if the text is short enough. If the text gets longer, it pushes the second one "from the card".

What should be changed that the first column takes only the available space?

```
Card(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(150.dp)
                .padding(bottom = 16.dp),
            elevation = 0.dp,
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(11.dp)
        ) {
            Row {
                Column(
                    Modifier
                        .padding(top = 11.dp, bottom = 13.dp, end = 12.dp, start = 16.dp),
                ) {
                    Text(
                        text = "First Text gets very long. Two long for Text the second text. It gets pushed out of the screen.",
                        fontSize = 16.sp,
                        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                        maxLines = 2,
                        overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
                    )
                }
                Spacer(Modifier.weight(1f))
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .width(86.dp)
                        .fillMaxHeight()
                ) {
                    Text(
                        text = "Second Text",
                        fontSize = 16.sp,
                        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                        maxLines = 2,
                        overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
                    )
                }
            }
        }
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply the `weight` modifier to the first `Column` removing the `Spacer`:

```
    Row(Modifier.height(IntrinsicSize.Min)) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "First ......screen.",
                //
                overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
            )
        }
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .width(86.dp)
                .fillMaxHeight()
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "Second Text",
                fontSize = 16.sp,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                maxLines = 2,
                overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
            )
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: `Row(Modifier.height(IntrinsicSize.Min)) {` @Gabriele Mariotti

Comment: Correct me if wrong the closing brackets made me some confusion, please check

Comment: @J.K Sorry my bad. Just missing a `)`

Comment: No mention please. you are true inspiration for us. Actually I was feared to comment this when i see your score. :)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I am happy if I can help others and every feedback is welcome.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti you are great teacher...